# wrap Intl.DateTimeFormat's format

Tags: javascript, isodate

I try to format an ISO date string with [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat).
Since it does not accept strings, I have tried to modified the instance's `format` function.

It returns an error:

> RangeError: Invalid time value

```
var str = '2018-05-30T12:20:51.526Z'
var date = new Date(str)

var dtf = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en');
var format = dtf.format;
dtf.format = function(str) {
  var date = new Date(str);
  return format(date);
}

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en').format(date)) // 5/30/2018
console.log(dtf.format(str))
```

Here is a [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/vemolajedo/1/edit?js,console,output) with the code.

Comment: so... what is the expected format you need in order for it to work? Cause you say it doesn't accept strings, so what does it accept?

Comment: @mrdeadsven as you can see in my code I construct a Date object from  the string, and it works with it. `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en').format(date)`.

Comment: yes ok, you now told me that it works.... so what is your question what do you wan to achieve? Are you trying to get the same result with the format function? or are you trying something else?

Comment: @mrdeadsven I try to get the same result,  The first `console.log` shows how the `dtf.format` function should work after the wrap. I try to avoid the need of creating Date object from ISOstring each and every time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could best use 'moment.js' to format it.

```js
var str = '2018-05-30T12:20:51.526Z'
var date = new Date(str)
  
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en').format(date))
console.log(moment(str).format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Import the 'moment' script in your HTML file and you can convert your ISO date to whatever format you want.